# XML parser recommendation for WatchKit extension

Tags: xml-parsing, swift2, watchkit, apple-watch

I am building an app that on hourly basis downloads/parses an XML file from internet and displays a specific field on a apple watch / watchkit complication.

My current app within ExtensionDelegate parses (in Swift2 using NSXMLParser) which works well on simulator but does not work on physical device (I assume it times out).

How do you parse in watchkit extension? use any add-ons?